# How can I refresh my Angular scope after AJAX call?

Tags: angularjs, ajax

My add to lightbox functionality here is not working: http://icon.pha-group.com/ because my Angular app is loaded before the AJAX content. I know I need to somehow call my Angular app from the AJAX success but Im not sure how. The reason for this is that on other pages the content isnt loaded dynamically. Here is the success:

```
$.ajax({
//url: bobz.ajax_url,
url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
data: {
    action: 'do_filter_posts',
nonce: bobz.nonce,
params: $params
},
type: 'post',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {

    if (data.status === 200) {
        $content.html(data.content);
    }
    else if (data.status === 201) {
        $content.html(data.message);    
    }
    else {
        $status.html(data.message);
    }

    //all done so call cycle script
    script_cycle();
    // Cookies.set('pageA-selection', '#page=3  ');
    //console.log(data.content);
 },
```

And here is start of my Angular add to lightbox app:

```
var app = angular.module('lightbox', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('lightboxCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

function IsJsonString(str) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


$http.get('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=lightbox_list_ajax').success(function(data) {

    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined" &&
        localStorage.getItem("lightbox_list") !== null ||
        localStorage.getItem("lightbox_list"))
    {
        var selectedOption = localStorage.lightbox_list;


    //} else if(data)
    //{
    //    var selectedOption = data[0];
    //
    //    localStorage.setItem("lightbox_list", JSON.stringify(selectedOption));

    }else{
        var selectedOption = null;
    }

    if(IsJsonString(selectedOption))
    {
        $scope.data = {
            availableOptions: data,
            selectedOption: JSON.parse(selectedOption) //This sets the default value of the select in the ui
        };

    }else{

        $scope.data = {
            availableOptions: data,
            selectedOption: selectedOption //This sets the default value of the select in the ui
        };
    }

console.log(selectedOption);
}).error(function(){
    console.log('unable to load lightbox lists');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$scope.$apply()` inside the ajax response

```
success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {

    if (data.status === 200) {
        $content.html(data.content);
    }
    else if (data.status === 201) {
        $content.html(data.message);    
    }
    else {
        $status.html(data.message);
    }

    //all done so call cycle script
    script_cycle();
    $scope.$apply()
 },
```

But note that it's very bad habbit to use the `$ajax` in angular. Use the `$http` service which is inbuild angular service and you don't need to call `$apply` in $http.

Comment: Thank you for your help but in the function there $scope is not defined - how do I solve this now?! :)

Comment: is this call implement in a service or factory ?

Comment: I dont know!! the AJAX is a seperate file to the angular app